# What methods have been used to cool aerospikes on paper and in reality?

Tags: engine-design, research, cooling, aerospike

I am doing a research project and need to mention what methods have been used to cool aerospikes (toroidal is the brute of the paper but I suppose methods for cooking toroidal Aerospikes could apply to linear ones as well) either on paper or in the few actual aerospikes that have hit the test stand. I have looked into the J-2t and a few other concepts but any official documentation or writes up would be amazing as this is a somewhat obscure topic that I have struggled to find info on.

Comment: Can you provide the list of actual aerospike engines that you wish additional information on?

Comment: @OrganicMarble the aerospikes that I know of that have hit the test stand that I am looking for documentation on are; The J-2t and the XRS-2200, in terms of aerospikes that have existed on paper I believe there are numerous different concepts but if there are any that you know of that stand out in quality, concept, documentation, or anything that would be greatly appreciated!